# Does environment server make global 3D representation with respect to static frame /odom or /map?

Tags: ros, collision-map, environment-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a collision efficient 3D global representation. I think environment server does this using collision map, but I am not sure and hence want to clear my doubts.

Does environment server take the collision maps and put them into global representation which should be with respect to some static frame like /odom or /map. So if next time it receives a new collision map from different location of mobile base (as collision map is centered around the mobile base frame) then it should update the global 3D representation. could someone show me the right direction?

If above is true then Can I save the global 3d representation (collision map) and reload it again in the future??

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11954/does-environment-server-make-global-3d-representation-with-respect-to-static-frame-/odom-or-/map-?/) by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 373 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, that kind of algorithms rely on TF to transform incoming sensor data into a global frame.

As you probably know, all your sensor data are supposed to carry a frame_id and a time stamp, which are used by TF to perform adequate transformations.

Checking the documentation of http://www.ros.org/wiki/planning_environment, you can find the following:

*~global_frame (string, default: "")
If the global frame is specified to be the empty string, the root frame in which all monitoring will take place is the root link of the robot ("base_link" for the robot). Otherwise, this parameter can be set to a fixed frame in the world (e.g. "odom_combined", "map")*

so in the end, it is up to you to chose what frame is to be used as reference.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-11-18**:
sorry, I never used this package. maybe check mapping_msgs, but it seems its API will undergo changes at it will move to using PCL. else, use the source luke ;)

**Comment by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on 2011-11-18**:
I am assuming that same parameter (global_frame) holds in electric as well. I need to set this parameter "global_frame" under "environment_server" node in launch file??  Can you please specify how collision map represents unknown space?

**Comment by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on 2011-11-18**:
Raphael: That makes sense. Actually I am using electric and in the starting of "planning_environment" documentation it says that most of the information on diamondback no longer holds so I didn't scroll down to read this information.